# Python connecting to MySQL Server through SSH tunneling

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector, ssh-tunnel

Hello I need help connecting remotely to my SQL Database thats hosted on my home server. I can connect ok using terminal, but when i try using pycharm i get the following error:

I've been getting a "Unix domain sockets not allowed for remoteaddress" error.
Im not sure which addresses i should be putting for Remote_server and Private_server as well as the last host= ip. If someone could help shed some light that would be awesome thank you!

Heres my code:
`import mysql.connector`
`import sshtunnel`

`with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(`
        `('REMOTE_SERVERIP', 3306),`
        `ssh_username='darren',`
        `ssh_password='darren',`
        `remote_bind_address=('xxxxxxx'),`
        `local_bind_address=('0.0.0.0')`
`) as tunnel:`
    `connection = mysql.connector.connect(`
        `user='darren',`
        `password='darren',`
        `host='xxxxxxx',`
        `database='SalesFindr',`
        `port=3306)`

Comment: Most MySQL implementations use the local UNIX socket instead of the port if you are connecting to `localhost:3306`. Try to map to a different port.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation, the **remote_bind_address()** must be a tuple consisting of both IP Address and Port

> remote_bind_address (tuple):
> Remote tuple in the format (`str`, `int`) representing the
> IP and port of the remote side of the tunnel.

We can leave the "Port" parameter empty only for local_bind_address.

> local_bind_address (tuple):
> Local tuple in the format (`str`, `int`) representing the
> IP and port of the local side of the tunnel. Both elements in
> the tuple are optional so both `('', 8000)` and
> `('10.0.0.1', )` are valid values
>
> ```
>        Default: ``('0.0.0.0', RANDOM_PORT)``
> ```

So, in your code, try `remote_bind_address=('xxxxxxx', 27018)` (or any free port in place of 27018)